# how to start h2o on sandbox after launching

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform, h2o

I have installed h2o on my hortonworks sandbox 2.1 platform which is on virtual box. It works fine at localhost:54321. But, when I restart virtual box, it does not launch at localhost:54321 again. How can I start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restart the virtual machine, you will also need to restart the H2O cluster.  You will start the H2O cluster like you did originally, which is probably by typing the following at the command line: `java -jar h2o.jar`   Once the H2O cluster is running again, you will be able to reach the Flow web interface at localhost:54321.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: It does not work for h2o flow on hortonworks. How should I do to start flow in hortonworks sandbox 2.4?

Comment: Here is the command to start H2O on Hadoop:  `hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -output hdfsOutputDirName`  More info here: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turan/4/index.html#Hadoop